# Protractor supports Windows Authentication pop up?

Tags: protractor

Is there a way that Protractor supports windows authentication pop up for IE and Chrome, this doesn't work for my application, "http://username:password@server.url/", are there any alternate ways through which we can handle windows pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome supports directly embedding credentials in URL and just works fine as "http://username:password@server.url/".

However IE does not support that as security issue so you may have to write a shell script as below:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "Windows Security"
WshShell.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "Username"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "password"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```